# Passing csv files between regions

Tags: localization, excel, csv

I have a desktop app that generates numerous csv files. The application *always* runs on PCs that have been configured for the `English (United Kingdom)` region/format, but it's feasible that files might get sent to people using PCs with non-UK regional settings.

I'm therefore curious to know what would happen if someone in (say) France - where commas are used as decimal points - was to try opening the following csv file in Excel:

```
1.123,2.456,"string1","string2",24-May-2018,17:35:59
```

Will it fail miserably? If so, what are the alternatives? I don't want to use a different delimiter (as it's no longer *comma*-delimited!), and would prefer not to have to start generating xls files instead.

Comment: You can mimic these environment settings by changing them on your local machine and see for yourself. If there is an answer, it is purely subject to whatever the developers of the third-party app they choose to open it in have catered for.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ yeah, I guess I was worried that there might be adverse effects in doing this. I'll give it a try...

Comment: Always good to have some environment (ideally not the same as your dev), mimic production.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after switching my PC's "Format" setting to 'French (France)' via control panel, I opened a csv in Excel containing the above line of text. Excel placed the *entire line* into a single cell. Not what I expected, but I guess if Excel can't separate the values (as commas are now D.P.s) then it can't parse the line and treats it as a single string.

Renaming the file to .txt and opening it in Excel, choosing a comma delimiter in the "text import" dialog, did result in the values being placed into separate cells. Only the time column was given a "custom" format, while the others were "general", which suggests it wasn't able to parse the date, which surprises me.

Opening the .txt in Excel when using "English (United Kingdom)" gave the numeric columns a "general" format, and both the date and time columns "custom" formats.

Comment: You don't have to rename the file, in Excel, there is a function to start the text import assistent directly for text in a selected column. In my german Excel, it is called "Text in Spalten" (literally "Text in columns", don't know if that is the term in the english Excel UI).

Answer (score 0):

CSV doesn't have an official specification, but the normal rule is if a value contains a comma it should be enclosed in quotes.

If you ran the code on a french computer, (say a minitel), I would expect the values to be correctly separated as they are not enclosed.

However, the numbers might fail to be parsed correctly into numeric types. You might have to specify say for example in c#

```
double.TryParse(doubleString, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out invariantCultureResult);
```

instead of

```
double.TryParse(doubleString);
```

Comment: [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) tries to standardize a minimum shared CSV subset, but support is meh – Excel in particular does its own thing.